# How to show that $p_{K}(x)<1$ iff $x$ is an interior point of convex set $K.$

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to prove theorem $3$, chapter $3$ from the book Functional Analysis, Peter Lax.

> **Definition 1** : Let $X$ be a linear space of reals and $S\subset X.$ A point $x_0$ is called an interior point of $S$ if $\forall y\in X,\exists \epsilon $ such that for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ with $|t|<\epsilon$ we have $x_0+ty\in S.$
>
> **Definition 2** : Let $K$ be a convex set that has an interior point. Define $$p_K(x)=\inf a, \text{ where }a>0 \text{ and }\frac{x}{a}\in K.$$
>
> **Theorem 3** : For any convex set $K$, $$p_K(x)<1 \iff x\text{ is an interior point of K}.$$

**My attempt**: 
For the forward direction, assume that there exists $x\in X$ such that $r = p_{K}(x)<1.$ Then we want to show that $x$ is an interior point of $K.$ Choose $y\in X,$ then I am not sure what $\epsilon$ to choose that will make $x+ty\in K$ for all $|t|<\epsilon.$

For the reverse direction, if $x$ is an interior point of $K$ then this means that 
$$p_K(x)\leq p_K(x-ty) + tp_K(y)\leq 1 + \epsilon p_K(y)$$ 
for some $y\in X$ and for all $|t|<\epsilon.$ Can I use this to show that $p_K(x)\leq 1?$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the other implication works. Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S \subset X$ be the closed square with vertices $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$ and $(1,1)$. Then $S$ has an interior point $(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.

Further for $x = (\frac{3}{2},0)$ we have $$p_S(x) \leq \frac{3}{4} < 1$$ as $(\frac{3}{4})^{-1}x = (2,0) \in S$. However, $x$ is not an interior point of $S$.

I think that the problem is that the condition of $p_S(x)$ takes into consideration only the line $\overline{0x}$ while being interior point considers all directions from $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x$, so that there's an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $|t|<\epsilon$ , $x+tx=(1+t)x\in S$.

Pick any such $t$ that satisfies $0<t<\epsilon$. Let $a_t:=1/(1+t)$. Then $p_K(x)\leq a_t<1.$

Comment: I am not sure that you can claim $a_t<1$ since $t$ can be negative.

Comment: I don't think you can fix $\varepsilon>0$ for all $y \in X$ but you can take $\varepsilon$ corresponding to $y=x$.

@model_checker it holds for all $|t| \leq y$, if $t$ is negative just take $-t$.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Do you have any suggestions for the other implication?

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets: Ah, you're right. I think I've patched the issue now.

Comment: @model_checker: For the forward direction, note that it is also assumed that $K$ has at least one interior point $z$.